# Is the function continuous at the indicated point?

Tags: calculus, continuity

$f(x) = x[x]$ at $x=2$ ($[x]$ is the greatest integer function)

I am little confused, it seems like the function does exist at the given point.
when limit goes to 2,
$2[2] = 4$
and $f(2) = 4$
so limit $f(2) = f(2)$
However, when thinking about limit, right-hand side has to be equal to left-hand side. But the function has a jump discontinuity.

so should I say it is continuous at the given point or not??

Comment: The limit of the products is the product of the limits, provided the limits exist. Now, take the sided limits of $[x]$ at $2$. What do you get? Since the limit of $x$ is $2$, your function is continuous at $2$ provided $[x]$ is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attempting to evaluate the limit of $f(x)$ as $x\to2$ by substituting $x=2$ and giving the answer $f(2)$.  In other words,
$$\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=f(a)\ .$$
This is true as long as $f(x)$ is continuous at $x=a$.  BUT in this case, that is exactly what the question is asking - is $f(x)$ continuous at $x=2$?  So you cannot use this approach.

As suggested in other posts, the best way to do this problem is to look at the left and right hand limits separately.  You could try thinking about the value of $[x]$ if $x$ is slightly less than, or slightly greater than $2$:
$$[x]=\cases{1&if $1\le x<2$\cr 2&if $2\le x<3$\cr}$$
and therefore
$$f(x)=x\,[x]=\cases{x&if $1\le x<2$\cr 2x&if $2\le x<3$.\cr}$$
Hence
$$\lim_{x\uparrow2}f(x)=\lim_{x\uparrow2}x=2
  \quad\hbox{and}\quad
  \lim_{x\downarrow2}f(x)=\lim_{x\downarrow2}2x=4\ .$$
Since the left and right hand limits are not equal, $\lim_{x\to2}f(x)$ does not exist.  Therefore $f(x)$ is not continuous at $x=2$.

Answer (score 1):

A function is not continous where it makes a jump because the limit must exist from the left and the right side and these limits must coincide and moreover, the value of the function must be the same as the limits.

Comment: so when thinking about limit, even the plugged-in x value has an outcome, we still need to think about right-hand and left-hand? like the function, 2[2] = 4 but not the left-hand side. so the function is continuos at right hand only?

Comment: Yes, exactly that. We can say, that the function is left- (or right-) continous in case of a jump.

Comment: Continous means left- and right-continous. And even if the limits coincide, the function is not continous if the value at the point does not coincide with the limits. So, continuity is quite a strong property. In particular, the function must be defined at the observed point.